# Restrictions for a full scholarship holder in Australia (applying working Visa after studies, full time work for spouse)

Tags: phd, masters, funding, international-students, australia

I am a B.Sc. (Food Science and Technology) degree holder with a 1st class, GPA – 3.82. I plan to apply for a full scholarship/full funding (MSc or PHD) in Australia.

I know that 20 hours/week is the legal maximum working hours for international full-time students in Australia who pay their own course fee.

I am wondering if I would have any restrictions like below as a full scholarship holder.

1. Are there any restrictions on me to work part-time while studying?
2. Are there any restrictions on me to apply for a working visa in Australia after completing the post graduate studies?
3. My spouse will come to Australia with me as my dependent. Will he be able to work full time or part-time?

Thanks for anyone who take the time to look at this.

Comment: Well, I can see my question has put on hold as off-topic. Then what about following questions? They also talking about the same topic. Please advise 

1.http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29652/can-i-get-a-job-while-still-applying-for-a-scholarship-for-phd-studies?rq=1, 

2.http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10686/restriction-on-working-hours-for-full-time-students?rq=1 

3.http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20445/two-simultaneous-part-time-masters-degrees-while-working-full-time?rq=1

Comment: 4.http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/how-is-it-to-work-full-time-and-do-a-part-time-phd?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I am not a lawyer . . . so please check out:

**Future Unlimited, studyinaustralia.gov.au**

- [home page](http://www.studyinaustralia.gov.au/) of this Australian government website.
- [How to apply](https://www.studyinaustralia.gov.au/global/apply-to-study/how-to-apply) You need to be enrolled before applying for a visa.

**Australian Government Department of Immigration and Border Protection**

- [home page](https://www.border.gov.au/)
- [studying in Australia](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Stud) for information on student visas
- [Student Visa (subclass 500)](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/500-) for general information
- [Work conditions for Student Visa Holders](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Stud/More/Work-conditions-for-Student-visa-holders) which indicates you can work up to 40 hours per fortnight in general, but perhaps in your case (post grad doing masters or PhD) unlimited hours. Your spouse or partner can work unlimited hours (because you are doing a masters or PhD). ***Nothing is mentioned about the paid or scholarship status of your studies.***
- [How to apply for a student visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Appl/Student).

Universities may be able to put you in touch with an agent they deal with to assist overseas students getting started. However, if it involves additional and expensive fees, consider if you really need to pay for additional assistance.

As mentioned I am not a lawyer and have simply helped people in the past to navigate government web sites. The student visa system has been updated and the information you quoted in the post as "known" may be out of date. Please contact the Department of Immigration and Borders if, after visiting their web site, you remain uncertain about how visa requirements will apply to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I will visit the links you have provided and gain more knowledge.